# removeAllChildren is not working in createjs

Tags: html5-canvas, createjs

I'm trying to change the bitmap image in createjs and want to remove all children in a container when reset button is clicked. But removeAllChildren is not working in me.

```
function drawPhoneImage() {
  stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas');
  container = new createjs.Container();

  phone = new createjs.Bitmap(phoneImg);
  phone.x = 268;
  phone.y = 64;

  stage.addChild(container);
  container.addChild(phone);
  stage.update();

  phone.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('phone clicked');
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", movePhoneImage);
  });
}

function movePhoneImage(event) {
  phone.x -=10;

  if(phone.x <  156) { 
    phone.x =156;
    showPhoneSnap();
  }
  stage.update(event);
}
```

Then after clicking the phone object, I'll need to replace it with another bitmap(which works):

```
function showPhoneSnap() {
  snap = new createjs.Bitmap(snapImg);
  snap.x = 156;
  snap.y = 64;

  container.removeAllChildren();
  container.addChild(snap);
  stage.update();
}
```

At first, removeAllChildren is working in the first child of the container, but when i tried resetting the stage after adding another bitmap in the container..removeAllChildren() is not working.

```
function resetStage() {
  container.removeAllChildren();
  stage.update();
}
```

I'm having a hard time solving this issue, thanks for anyone who can help.

Comment: How is `resetStage()` being called? Are there any errors logged during the call?

Comment: $('#reset').click(function() {
      resetStage();
    });

There's no error showing.

Comment: One presumption was, that the scope was maybe wrong, but in that case, it would raise an error of `stage` and `container` being `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "snapImg" is an image that is loaded.

```
snap = new createjs.Bitmap(snapImg);
```

The issue is that you are not updating the stage when the image is loaded.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "path";
image.onload = showPhoneSnap;
function showPhoneSnap() {
    //This will ensure that the image is ready.
    var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(this);
    ...
    stage.update();
}
```